# How to update from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 after EOL

Tags: 22.04, 21.10

I cannot use anything including apt nor lose any type of user data nothing is working right now. Software updater doesn't work help at all and booting iso has only options that erase everything

Comment: The EOL annoucements included details on the *release-upgrade* process; you're too late for that, without also applying the EOLUpgrades process (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades).   Note **after** EOL, mirrors can drop support for any EOL release; thus additional changes (including purges) maybe necessary if using 3rd party sources; so what's required for you can vary depending on your system (is it server? desktop? as you didn't say).

Comment: Desktop systems are pretty easy to deal with & you can *upgrade via re-install* (*again what packages esp. 3rd party you have installed can complications even with this; none though would be expected if you only use Ubuntu repository software*)  FYI:  I'm involved with support & QA; when I no longer need a system for support purpose (*due to EOL usually*); I *upgrade via re-install* it to another later release..  21.10 became *kinetic* (22.10) as I had no need for another 22.04 system.. no loss of data or *manually installed* packages... That system isn't upgraded; but QA re-installed weekly